# incompatible pointer type sending NSString to parameter of type NSDate* _Nonnull ios Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have the following code. Here I tried two methods to get the date and time. If i use formatter it gives me the above error. If I do not use it the date format is not correct and plus the time which i get is also incorrect. Kindly help.

```
NSDate *pickupHoursLate;
NSDate *dropHoursLate;

formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSLog(@"Old Date and Time : %@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

this give me output like this **12-07-2016 18:32** which I want

```
NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    int pickHoursToAdd = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"pickupPriorTimePeriod"] intValue];
    [components setHour:pickHoursToAdd];
    pickupHoursLate = [calender dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] options:0];
```

This Line gives me the **error**

```
int dropHoursToAdd = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dropPriorTimePeriod"] intValue];
[components setHour:dropHoursToAdd];
dropHoursLate = [calender dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

This Line gives me the value **2016-07-12 15:02:51 +0000** after adding 2 hrs to current time but here the time is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
    NSDate *pickupHoursLate;
NSDate *dropHoursLate;

formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSLog(@"Old Date and Time : %@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]); **<this give me output like this 12-07-2016 18:32 which I want>**
NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
int pickHoursToAdd = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"pickupPriorTimePeriod"] intValue];
[components setHour:pickHoursToAdd];

//Editing start
NSString *dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] ;
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
    pickupHoursLate = [calender dateByAddingComponents:components toDate: date options:0];    **<This Line gives me the error>**
//Editing  End

int dropHoursToAdd = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dropPriorTimePeriod"] intValue];
[components setHour:dropHoursToAdd];
dropHoursLate = [calender dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];   **<This Line gives me the value "2016-07-12 15:02:51 +0000" after adding 2 hrs to current time but here the time is incorrect>**
```

Comment: Printing description of dateStr:
12-07-2016 19:04
Printing description of date:
2016-07-12 13:34:00 +0000
Printing description of self->pickupHoursLate:
2016-07-12 19:34:00 +0000

Still the same issue is coming

Comment: Okay got it... Changed the code see now... added timeZone to formatter

Comment: Printing description of dateStr:
12-07-2016 19:11

Printing description of date:
2016-07-12 13:41:00 +0000

Printing description of self->pickupHoursLate:
2016-07-12 19:41:00 +0000

Comment: dateStr is giving correct date. But when converting it to date, I get incorrect value.

Comment: Check if can change the system timezone